# Dual boot grub rescue - nothing seems to help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I tried installing xubuntu on live CD like Ubuntu and now when I try tto boot my PC i get grub erorr.

Reason why Im posting this is because nothing seems to work for me. When I type ls (smth, smth) it says 'missing ) symbol' and when I add it; it displays the same thing.

Also I cant insmod normal. It also requies ) but when I add it, it says unkown partition

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Also i dont own any repair dics. I installed w10 via mediacreations.

Comment: First make Windows repair/recovery flash drive. Boot Ubuntu live installer in live mode and run Summary report from Boot-Repair. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I used windows app called live usb. I looked up a bit about widnows recovery/repair but i couldnt find anything. Can you guide me?

Comment: My one Windows system strongly suggested both a Dell recovery and a Windows recovery on first boot.  Which I did but also did a full image backup with Macrium: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2137439&p=12611710#post12611710 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive Multiple flash drives required. But for Ubuntu we need the link to the summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: I was reading about it. But they (writters) point out on a active system. I cant get Ubuntu or Windows running. I cant even boot it. So it will work if I burn it on a cd and put it in my *broken* pc just like that?

Comment: Then you need to boot Ubuntu live installer in live mode and run the Summary report. Then post link so we can see your exact configuration.